# Get Process that added a Subkey to a specific Registrykey

Tags: c#, registry, monitor, registrykey

I used the [RegistryMonitor-Wrapper](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4502/RegistryMonitor-a-NET-wrapper-class-for-RegNotifyC) to create an application that notifies the user when a Subkey is added to a specific Regsitrykey. 
Now I want my application to tell the user which process created that Subkey.

Is that possible?

Comment: Without reading all the source - it would suggest that this is not visible.  Have you tried asking the guys who write it?

Comment: Sorry I guess you've got me wrong. I don't want to know if there's a "built-in" possiblity in the RegistryMonitor-Wrapper to do so. I'd like to know if there is any possibility in general to get the information which process created a specific subkey inside the registry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to monitor registry access *as it happens*, that's what e.g. ProcMon from Sysinternals is doing (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon). For some information on how that might work, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4835195/9272280

If you are asking whether it's possible to find out *after the fact*, which process created a given subkey: I believe the answer to that would be no.